# Vertica SQL GO library supports backup_server_node options , Does anyone know after how many minutes it will connect to secondary host?

Tags: sql, go, vertica

vertica-sql-go library supports backup_server_node options , Does anyone know after how many minutes it will take to connect to secondary host ?
https://github.com/vertica/vertica-sql-go

backup_server_node
a list of backup hosts for the client to try to connect if the primary host is unreachable  a comma-seperated list of backup host-port pairs. E.g.
'host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3'

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with this setup in odbc.ini:

```
[sbx1]
Description = Vertica database
Driver = Vertica
Database = sbx
Servername = sbx0
BackupServerNode = sbx1,sbx2,sbx3
Port = 5433
ConnectionLoadBalance = TRUE
DriverStringConversions = NONE
ThreePartNaming = FALSE
ColumnsAsChar = TRUE
```

... where I happen to know that `sbx0` is currently unreachable. (ODBC works like JDBC and any other connecting protocols).

This one (a different DSN) took 0.947 seconds:

```
Connecting as dbadmin to sbx2 ...
_tm_connect     00:00:00.947
```

This one - connecting to DSN `sbx1`, the one with the failing primay host, immediately afterwards, took 14 seconds and change:

```
Connecting as dbadmin to sbx1 ...
_tm_connect     00:00:14.092
```

So, in my case, around 14 seconds ...